# replace words in a string and re join them

Tags: ruby, string, replace, split

Hi I'm building a function that has me take any instance of "u" or "you" in a string and replace it with a specific word.  I can go in and isolate the instances no problem but I cannot get the words to output properly.  So far I have.

```
def autocorrect(input)

 #replace = [['you','u'], ['your sister']]
 #replace.each{|replaced| input.gsub!(replaced[0], replaced[1])}
 input.split(" ")

 if (input == "u" && input.length == 1) || input == "you"
   input.replace("your sister")
 end

 input.join(" ")
end
```

The ideal output would be:

```
autocorrect("I am so smitten with you")

"I am smitten with your sister"
```

I don't know how to get the last part correct, I can't think of a good method to use.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `input == "u"` implies that `input.length` is 1. The latter check is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with your code is that you call `input.split(" ")` but you don't save that to anything, and then you check for `input == "u" # ...`, and `input` is still the entire string, so if you called `autocorrect('u')` or `autocorrect('you')` you would get `"your sister"` back, **except** for the next line: `input.join(" ")` will throw an error.

This error is because, remember `input` is still the original string, not an array of each word, and strings don't have a `join` method.

To get your code working with the fewest changes possible, you can change it to:

```
def autocorrect(input)
  #replace = [['you','u'], ['your sister']]
  #replace.each{|replaced| input.gsub!(replaced[0], replaced[1])}
  input.split(" ").map do |word|
    if (word == "u" && word.length == 1) || word == "you"
      "your sister"
    else
      word
    end
  end.join(" ")
end
```

So, now, you *are* doing something with each word after you `split(" ")` the input, and you are checking each word against `"u"` and `"you"`, instead of the entire input string. You then map either the replacement word, or the original, and then join them back into a single string to return them.

---

As an alternative, shorter way, you can use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) which can take a `Hash` as the second parameter to do substitutions:

> If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

```
def autocorrect(input)
  replace = { 'you' => 'your sister',
              'u' => 'your sister',
              'another word' => 'something else entirely' }

  input.gsub(/\b(#{replace.keys.join('|')})\b/, replace)
end

autocorrect("I am u so smitten with utopia you and another word")
# => "I am your sister so smitten with utopia your sister and something else entirely"
```

the regex in that example comes out looking like:

```
/\b(you|u|another word)\b/
```

with `\b` being any word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple array mapping would do the job:

```
"I am u so smuitten with utopia you".split(' ').map{|word| %w(you u).include?(word) ? 'your sister' : word}.join(' ')
#=> "I am your sister so smuitten with utopia your sister"
```

Your method would be:

```
def autocorrect(input)
  input.split(' ').map{|word| %w(you u).include?(word) ? 'your sister' : word}.join(' ')
end

autocorrect("I am so smitten with you")
#=> "I am smitten with your sister"
```